# Como puedo sumar la cantidad " T1.cantidad" de la misma tabla y el mismo consecutivo

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

```
USE  PORCIPOS

SELECT  T0.consecutivo, T0.fecha, T0.codtipodcto, T0.codigo, T1.cantidad , T1.valor, T1.hydra, T1.codigo
FROM [dbo].[tblencfacturas] T0 INNER JOIN tblmvtofacturas T1 ON T0.consecutivo = T1.consecutivo 
WHERE T0.consecutivo = '1081557940' 
GROUP BY  cantidad
```

[image: resultado]

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar:

```
SUM( T1.cantidad ) OVER( PARTITION BY T0.consecutivo ) cantidad
```

sin **GROUP BY**

Comment: Hola, Guillermo ya intente haciendo esto pero me sale error que tengo que meter todo el select en el group by  y funciona pero no hace la suma

Comment: Tenes toda la razón me falto poner dentro del group by. Que columnas queres mostrar a parte de la columna cantidad?

Comment: necesito mostrar todas las columnas que están en el select pero cantidad necesito sumarla que me aparezca  5.000000+2.500000 =  7.500000 que salga el resultado en la consulta

Answer (score 0):

prueba con el comando SUM,

```
SELECT T0.consecutivo, 
       T0.fecha, 
       T0.codtipodcto, 
       T0.codigo, 
       SUM(T1.cantidad) cantidad, 
       T1.valor, 
       T1.hydra, 
       T1.codigo
FROM [dbo].[tblencfacturas] T0
     INNER JOIN tblmvtofacturas T1 ON T0.consecutivo = T1.consecutivo
WHERE T0.consecutivo = '1081557940'
GROUP BY T0.consecutivo, 
         T0.fecha, 
         T0.codtipodcto, 
         T0.codigo, 
         T1.valor, 
         T1.hydra, 
         T1.codigo;
```